# How do I load an image in vuetify when the link is in my filtered array?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to load different images, depending on the card.

```
<tr v-for="location in filteredLocation" v-bind:key="location">
    <v-card class="mx-auto">
      <v-img
        class="white--text align-end"
        height="200px"
        src="{{location.imgLink}}"
      ></v-img>
       </v-card>
    <br />
  </tr>
```

My filteredLocation is loading different locations from my array. In that array, the "imgLink" has different links. How do I make the src dynamic so each card loads a different image?

Answer (score 0):

This are Vue.js basics. Just binde the prop:

```
<tr v-for="location in filteredLocation" v-bind:key="location">
    <v-card class="mx-auto">
      <v-img
        class="white--text align-end"
        height="200px"
        :src="location.imgLink"
      ></v-img>
       </v-card>
    <br />
  </tr>
```